# Trying to create cabal package: parse error on `exposed-modules`

Tags: haskell, package, cabal

I'm trying to create a cabal library package named foo.
The sourcefiles I'm trying to include are: A2_5.hs, A7_1.hs, A8_1.hs, profiling.hs

I have the following in my foo.cabal file:

```
Name:               Foo
Version:            1.0
Cabal-Version:      >= 1.2
Author:             Chiel92
License:            GPL
License-file:       LICENSE
Category:           Educational Assignment
Description:        Description here
Build-Type:         Simple
data-files:         README.md

Library
  Build-Depends:    base, criterion
  Exposed-modules:  A2_5,
                    A7_1,
                    A8_1,
                    profiling
```

However, when running `cabal configure` I'm getting an error:

```
cabal: foo.cabal:14: Parse of field 'exposed-modules' failed.
```

What is going wrong?

**EDIT: The weird thing is: when omit the `profiling` part, it goes fine**

Comment: Did you use spaces to indent or tabs? (Use spaces, it's easier to get right)

Comment: How is it that you have a module that starts with a lower case letter?

Comment: the filename is lowercase, and I didn't explicitly specify the modulename. But apperently it indeed had to be an uppercase.

Comment: what if its an executable not a library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Omitting "profiling" makes it work because "profiling" is not a valid module name.  Module names start with upper case letters.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: when I write `Profiling` starting with an uppercase, it works! So apparently the modules that are exposed have to start with an uppercase, even though their filename is lowercase.